# Update the UI ( Loading and Error Views ) on RecyclerView using RxJava

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have a SearchView that executes a network request to search for some tracks and then populates a RecylerView with the results. I have found this code which works fine.

I have already integrated the RecyclerView EmptyView through the Adapter but now I am trying to integrate the LoadingView(Progress) and ErrorView inside this code. I tried to put the LoadingView(ProgressBar) on Visibility True inside the concatMap but got the error that the  “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.” which can be solved running that on the MainThread but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Can someone have a better idea where and how the logic about show/hide the ErrorView and LoadingView can be integrated into this code?

I am using also RxBinding. Maybe also using RxRecyclerView would be a good idea?

```
 RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView).
            filter(charSequence ->
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.DAYS.MILLISECONDS)
            .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .concatMap(searchTerm ->
                    {



                        return  searchTracks(searchTerm).
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable1 -> {
                                            //handle error somehow, change UI

                                            return Observable.empty();
                                        }

                                );

                    }
            )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(tracks -> {


                populateTracks(tracks);

                    }
                });


            }, throwable -> {

            //show errorView


            });
```

Comment: Do you have access to the activity in here? If so, [`activity.runOnUiThread(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is your friend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This here was my complete solution without stripping code for the presentation.

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .skip(1)
    .doOnNext(charSequence -> Log.v(TAG, "searching: " + charSequence))
    .throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .onBackpressureLatest()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .filter(charSequence -> {
        final boolean empty = TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence);
        if (empty) {
            Log.v(TAG, "empty view");
            mAdapter.clear();
        }
        return !empty;
    })
    .concatMap(charSequence -> {
        Log.v(TAG, "requesting " + charSequence);
        return onErrorResumeNext(
                mGitApiService.searchRepositoriesSingle(charSequence.toString())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),
                throwable -> {
                    try {
                        throw throwable;
                    } catch (HttpException httpException) {
                        showEmptyErrorView(httpException.message());
                    } catch (Throwable other) {
                        showEmptyErrorView(other.getMessage());
                        other.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return Observable.empty();
                });
    })
    .doOnNext(charSequence -> Log.v(TAG, "got data"))
    .subscribe(response -> {
        showRepositories(response.getItems());
    }, throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        showEmptyErrorView(throwable.getMessage());
    });
```

so basically whenever you touch your view you have to call `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: **so basically whenever you touch your view you have to call .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())** Part should be highlighted as that's the most important thing. Basically, you should be in the same thread when you are dealing with one another.This case debounce sits in Computation thread but the view is in Main thread.